# find the fastest time between different times is returning the wrong answer in c++

Tags: c++

The code below is supposed to take in a value N that specifies how many different time u will receive. The entire code will the imputed time in the format HH:MM:SS and compare it to each other then show which time is the fastest for ex: lets say the input is

```
4
10:15:46
03:59:08
04:00:08
03:59:09
```

and it should return 03:59:08 but when i run this code it returns 03:59:09 and ive been scratching my head around this as to why its happening.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int n;

    cin >> n;
    string p;
    string fast = "00:00:00";
    cin >> fast;
    for (int i = 0; i < n - 1; i++) {
        cin >> p;
        for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++) {
            if (p[j] - '0' < fast[j] - '0') {
                fast = p;
                break;
            }
        }
        cin.ignore();
    }
    cout << fast;
}
```

Comment: Did you try to use a debugger to step line by line through your code?

Comment: Your logic is incorrect. It considered `04:00:08` to be less than `03:59:08` because `0' is less than `5`.

Comment: When doing calculations like that, always use concrete representations (like a single time-stamp for time instead of hh:mm:ss)

Comment: Convert the time to seconds, then compare.

Comment: Yeah i just now noticed it and i basically add an else if (p[j] - '0' > fast[j] - '0')
   {
    break;
   } and it now works

Comment: also i changed fast to "99:99:99" and removed the cin >> fast.

Comment: [Convert to seconds](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8121389b72d850b6).  All of this comparison to '0' and other things you're doing need not be done if you wrote a very simple function to take that string and convert it to seconds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your logic, you have `p[j] - '0' < fast[j] - '0'`. This fails in most cases. Let's look at `04:00:08` (the current `p`) and `03:59:08` (the current `fast`).

Let's do comparisons character be character now:

```
'0' < '0' // false, so continue
'4' < '3' // false, so continue
':' < ':' // false, so continue
'0' < '5' // true, set fast = p, then exit loop
```

You need to break earlier, in the case when `fast` is less than `p`. Here's your if statement modified for these cases:

```
if ( p[j] < fast[j] ) {
    fast = p;
    break;
} else if ( p[j] > fast[j] ) {
    break;
}
```

Note that I removed the `- '0'` since it's not necessary. What this will do, with the same example as above:

```
'0' < '0' // false, continue
'0' > '0' // false, continue
'4' < '3' // false, continue
'4' > '3' // true, break out of loop without changing fast
```

Of course, this is just a character by character comparison. Doing a simple `p < fast` would also work, or using `std::min` as Thomas Sablik says

Comment: so if i want to compare character values like '5' and '6' i wouldnt need to subtract by - '0' to convert it to a int?

Comment: @Astros257: `a + x < b + x`  <=> `a < b`.

Comment: Thank you very much i didn't know this and this will surely help me clean up my code lol

Answer (score 2):

Your sort algorithm is wrong. Instead you can use STL functions:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using std::cin;
using std::cout;
using std::min;

int main()
{
    int n;

    cin >> n;
    string p;
    string fast;
    cin >> fast;
    for (int i = 0; i < n - 1; i++) {
        cin >> p;
        fast = std::min(fast, p);
        cin.ignore();
    }
    cout << fast;
}
```

Comment: huh i never thought about it this way. I thought of using the min function but i thought since the string has a character like ':' it would give me bad results.

Comment: is there any reason you set fast to `"00:00:00"` before reading user input? I mean if `>>` fails anyhow you end up with an empty string

Comment: @Astros257 `std::min` wont compare the numbers in the string but the characters (which is basically the same ;)

Comment: well what my goal was to compare the time fast by value and i needed a starting point so i set it to a default value but i just also relized that if i leave it at "00:00:00" it will always output that since its the lowest so i changed it "99:99:99".

Comment: @formerlyknownas_463035818 I copied it from the question and removed it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code, you will find out what's wrong:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int n;

    stringstream os;

    cin >> n;
    string p;
    string fast = "00:00:00";
    cin >> fast;
    for (int i = 0; i < n - 1; i++)
    {
        cin >> p;
        for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++)
        {
            if (p[j] - '0' < fast[j] - '0')
            {
                os << "replace " << fast << " by " << p << " because of " << j << " : " << fast[j] << " vs. " << p[j] << endl;
                fast = p;
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                os << j << " : " << fast[j] << " vs. " << p[j] << " ; " << fast[j] - '0' << " vs. " << p[j] - '0' << endl;
            }
        }
        cin.ignore();
    }
    cout << endl
         << endl;
    cout << fast;
    cout << endl
         << endl;
    cout << os.str();
}
```

It is import to learn how to design a debug code to find out the bug(s). So you'b better find out the bug according the code above before seeing the solution below

(By the way, reduce a same number on both side is unnecessary: "p[j] - '0' < fast[j] - '0'" is the same as "p[j] < fast[j]")

Here is a possible solution:

```
if (p[j] == fast[j])
{
    continue;
}
if (p[j] < fast[j])
{
    fast = p;
}
// else p[j] > fast[j]
break;
```